# How to save and use latin unicode in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unicode

How can I use accented Latin characters like these (or any other unicode char really) in my `echo` statements comments?

```
À à Á á Â â Ã ã
É é Ê ê 
Í í 
Ó ó Õ õ
Ú ú
Ç ç
Ñ ñ
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: So far noting but when I save the file in gedit I get the diamond shaped character instead.

Comment: Check what encoding `gedit` and your terminal emulator is configured for. Everything should be configured for utf-8, unless there is good reason otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Unixes use utf-8, this is the same as 7bit-ascii, but has extension bytes for other unicode characters. If your terminal is set to utf-8, then you can paste in the characters in you question.

e.g.

```
echo À à Á á Â â Ã ã
```

If you wish to type them, then I suggest enabling a compose key.
Then you can type <kbd>compose</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> for Ã. Or <kbd>compose</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd> for ☺.